# ColumnStyle doesn't work property

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I want to add TableLayoutPanel dynamically. Also, I want to set the width of columns dynamically. Below is the code I have written to get the required results. But it doesn't work property. I have attached the image of the output of this code. Please help... It is just a test code, I want to learn creating controls dynamically, positin them, styling them etc...

```
private void ShowAllRecords() {
    TableLayoutPanel[] tab = new TableLayoutPanel[MaxRows];
    for (int rNumber = 0; rNumber < 1; rNumber++)
    {
        tab[rNumber] = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tab[rNumber].ColumnStyles.Clear();
        tab[rNumber].RowCount = 1;
        tab[rNumber].ColumnCount = 2;
        tab[rNumber].CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset;
        tab[rNumber].Location = new Point(0, (rNumber * 50) + 100);
        tab[rNumber].Width = 200;
        TableLayoutColumnStyleCollection styles = tab[rNumber].ColumnStyles;
        tab[rNumber].ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 10));

        panel1.Controls.Add(tab[rNumber]);
        tab[rNumber].BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an error in the for loop: you're always iterating only once instead of `MaxRows` times. Replace this:

```
for (int rNumber = 0; rNumber < 1; rNumber++)
```

with this:

```
for (int rNumber = 0; rNumber < MaxRows; rNumber++)
```

Now you'll create a desired number of `TableLayoutPanel`'s with first fixed width column, stacked one below the other and partially overlapping. You should probably also set the `Height`, but it's difficult to guess what exactly you're trying to achieve.